# Python program running in Spyder python but not Windows 10 Command Prompt

Tags: python, command-line, spyder

I am trying to run a program from the command prompt window on my windows 10 machine. It works perfectly in spyder but on the command line, it hangs at the "canvas.show()" line and says invalid fmt string. Can anyone think of why this is happening? This function is called when someone presses a button on a GUI. I am using python 2.7.10 on the command prompt and Spyder(python 2.7)

```
class PageThree(tk.Frame):
    def refreshFigure(self):
        #accesses spectral data

        filename = askopenfilename()
        f = open(filename)

        temp = []
        xcoordinates = []
        ycoordinates = []
        dates = []
    ##########separates out time from irradiance
        while True:
            file_contents = f.readline()
            if file_contents:
                temp.append(file_contents.split('\t'))
            if not file_contents: break

        n = 0
        for n in range(len(temp)):
           xcoordinates.append(temp[n][0])
           ycoordinates.append(temp[n][2])

        f.close()
        np_ycoordinates = np.array(ycoordinates)
        m = 0
        for m in range (len(xcoordinates)):
            dates.append(dt.datetime.strptime(xcoordinates[m], '%H:%M:%S.%f'))


    # graph new data--Note, can only display 2 graphs
        f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
        a = f.add_subplot(111)
        a.plot(dates, np_ycoordinates, 'bo', dates, np_ycoordinates, 'k')


        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
        canvas.show()########### causing error????
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, self)
        toolbar.update()
        canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
```

Comment: What prints out when you type just `python` in your cmd prompt? Is it the version you expected? Do you have multiple versions of python on this machine?

Comment: it prints "Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:40:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information." This is what I expect. I only have python 2.7 on my computer.